# Barra desplazamiento horizontal no aparece

Tags: css, css3

Estoy teniendo problemas debido a que:

La página puede subir o bajar gracias a la barra vertical pero la barra horizontal no aparece y esta en `"auto"` y pierdo muchísimos datos de la página que si se hace más pequeña la ventana no aparecen.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: podrias agregar todo tu codigo osea el codigo css y la parte de la barra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas que se muestre la barra de desplazamiento en algun elemento html (como un div) puede utilizar:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

esto le indica a tu elemento que si sus hijos superan su ancho, entonces debe mostrar la barra de desplazamiento para poder mostrar el "exceso" de contenido.